# Pulling data into Google Sheets from Zenloop using Zenloop's API and Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-oauth, httprequest, urlfetch

I'm trying to automatically pull survey data from Zenloop (survey tool) into Google sheets by using Apps Script. When executing the function, it comes up with the following error:

Error:

> Exception: Request failed for `https://api.zenloop.com` returned code 401. Truncated server response: {"error":{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","status":401,"title":"Invalid or expired token."}} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

Script:

```
    function myFunction() {
      const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    };
    
    UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.zenloop.com/v1/survey_groups/XXXXXXXXXXX/answers?date_shortcut=all_time&order_type=desc&page=1', options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
```

I've X'd out the API key and survey ID. I'm brand new to Apps Script/Javascript so any here would be very much appreciated. There is no issue with the API Key or Survey ID, I've triple checked.

Comment: `contentType` is an advanced parameter. You could try removing `Content-Type` from the headers and adding it as an option key.  `options = { 'method' : 'get',  'contentType': 'application/json'`, Also, the Authorization is usually `Authorization: "Bearer " + "Key"`

Comment: As the additional information for @Alan Wells 's comment, `UrlFetchApp.fetch` doesn't return Promise. So `then` and `catch` cannot be used. In this case, how about using the method of `getContentText()`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)